# Why doesn't my program stay logged into a website after connecting?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape information about applicants for jobs but after `s.post(login_url, data=payload)` the session gets reset and the program no longer has access to the website content. I have tested it with just the logging in and it works fine, but when I try to access `interviews_url = ('https://www.sparkhire.com/company/interviews')` it logs me out. Am I doing something wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import token_scraper

login_url = ('https://www.sparkhire.com/login')
interviews_url = ('https://www.sparkhire.com/company/interviews')
payload = {
    '_token':token_scraper.token,
    'email':'censored', 
    'password':'censored'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    r = s.get(interviews_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0'
}


def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = get_soup(r.text)
        data = {
            "_token": soup.select_one('input[name=_token]')['value'],
            "email": "any@any.com",
            "password": "yourpass"
        }
        req.post(url, data=data)
        r = req.get('https://www.sparkhire.com/company/interviews')
        with open('view.html', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)


main('https://www.sparkhire.com/login')
```

Comment: I tried this and is is still getting logged out and returned to the login page after trying to interact with the website. Is it possible that the website has something in place preventing automated programs from interacting with it?